# How to call a templated function with a parameter in the template?

Tags: c++

I've this function:

```
template <typename T, T sep>
void split (){
    std::cout << sep << std::endl;    
}
```

When I try to call it with this command: `split<'f'>();`

I get the following error:

```
q3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
q3.cpp:36:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘split()’
     split<'f'>();
                ^
q3.cpp:36:16: note: candidate is:
q3.cpp:31:6: note: template<class T, T sep> void split()
 void split (){
      ^
q3.cpp:31:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Why?

Comment: What is the purpose of having the separator being a template argument instead of a function argument? Why not e.g. `template<typename T> void split(T const& sep) { ... }`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Learning purposes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why?

Because the first template parameter is a type, not a value. `'f'` is character constant, a value. And you cannot plug it in for a type.

A correct call would be `split<char, 'f'>()`.

In the upcoming C++17 standard, you can in fact redefine your template in a way that allows the syntax you want:

```
template <auto sep>
void split (){
    std::cout << sep << std::endl;    
}
```

Now the call `split<'f'>()` will deduce the type of `sep`.

Comment: Good use of C++17 `template<auto>` ...:-)

Comment: Is it possible to define a function that being called with this command `split<'c'>("ABcDEcA")` ?

Comment: @TheLogicGuy - Yes. `template<char> void split(std::string const&) { }`

Comment: @StoryTeller How to use the char that was passed in the <>? EDIT: I see that the answer is already written in your answer

Comment: @TheLogicGuy - Give the parameter a name. Then you can refer to it. Besides, you only asked how to define a function that will work with that syntax. I did. If you want it to do something meaningful, you better be clearer about it.